# Intent: default application option not shown

Tags: android

I'm using an Intent to let the users select an existing image on the Android device. Using the following or similar code, the createChooser Intent does show multiple options for selecting the image on the device (ASTRO, Gallery, etc), but doesn't show the "use by default for this action" checkbox.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/jpg");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        PICK_IMAGE);
```

I really must be overlooking something here. I compiled the app against 2.1, 2.2 and 4.0.3 to no avail. Tried on my Nexus S, the Galaxy S and the emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `createChooser()`, there will not be a "use by default for this action" checkbox. If you want that checkbox, get rid of `createChooser()` and just pass in `intent` to `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Thank you for that valuable info!